# WebDriverIO + VSC + JavaScript - Xpath with //* is treated as comment

Tags: selenium, xpath, webdriver-io

I am developing a UI framework using WebDriverIO in VSC. Now everything works fine but when I use an XPath like following, everything after //* is treated as a comment. How do I rectify this?

```
const obj=await (await someDashboard.$firstElement).$("//*[text()[contains(.,'ABCD')]])[1]")
```

[image]
Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Does it interfere with your code or you don't like how it looks visually?

Comment: It interferes with my code . Entire line after //* is treated as a comment and disabled.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this. Maybe a full screen shot can help.

Comment: added screen shot

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the game, but have you tried using backticks in your query?

```
const obj=await (await someDashboard.$firstElement).$(`//*[text()[contains(.,'ABCD')]])[1]`)
```